# Query a Parse User

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am creating an app in android that allows the user to search other users registered in the app.

Each user is asked to enter a set of details like "Date of Birth" before entering into the app.These data are directly stored in the user class.

My requirement is that if a user enters a username and searches he must be able to see all the details available on that particular user.
For eg.:Lets assume every user must have a email(String) and date of birth(String).An User searches for name "John". What should the query be so that I can retrieve both email and DOB of a user with username "John".

The data given in the Parse.com guide is

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("username", name);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Query Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Query Not Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

1. What are the changes that I need to make so that I can achieve my goal?
2. How to access the string stored inside the object?
3. If I retrieve multiple records from my query how can I handle it?

I have edited my query like this

```
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereMatches("username", name);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for(ParseUser singleobject:objects){
                        String mail=singleobject.get("email").toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mail,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Query Not Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
               }
            });
```

No toast is generated but the query is executed without any exception.

Is the looping statement correct or am i doing something wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What are the changes that I need to make so that I can achieve my goal?

The code looks like it correctly queries ParseUser for an *exact* match of a username. To match more loosely, consider using `whereMatches`

> 2. How to access the string stored inside the object?

`Parse.Object` provides `getString()` as well as other "get" variations depending on the attribute type.

> 3. If I retrieve multiple records from my query how can I handle it?

The "objects" parameter of the `findInBackground` completion handler is an array that contains zero or more matches to the query. Handle this array the way you would any other.